# Multiple things belonging to a group of people?

Tags: grammar, possessives, syntactic-analysis

This phrase is coming up over and over in the paper I'm editing... basically the author is talking about the many different things all belonging to a group of people. For example (these are not the phrase in question, but variations):

"...preliminary assessment of female athletes' perceptions of nutrition..."

"...gain a better understanding of females athletes' needs and interest in nutrition..."

"...the relationship between nutrition and performance from the male athletes' perspectives will be..."

These phrases all just feel awkward, but it comes up so often (these are all from the same short paragraph) that I feel it would be disruptive to the flow to always insert an 'of', e.g. "gain a better understanding of the needs and interest of females athletes in nutrition". Is there a proper way to write these sentences?

I also don't want to reduce the plural athletes or plural perspectives, as one of the main goals of the paper is that there are many athletes, and they each have a different perspective or perception or opinion that should not be amalgamated.

Comment: See: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22female+athletes%27+perceptions%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#tbm=bks&q=%22female+athletes%27+perceptions+of%22 for similar stuff.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on the Writers site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentences you used for illustration are perfectly grammatical (except for the mistake Hellion caught: "<s>females</s> female athletes'") and they don't feel awkward to me. You can tweak sentence order to add a little interest, but you're pretty well stuck either using the possessive (as you've shown there) or the genitive (which you wanted to avoid).

> ... gain a better sense of what female athletes need and their interest in nutrition...

Comment: Except for that one that says "female**s** athletes' needs"....

Comment: @Hellion Good catch!